How to create a value class like byte
in C#, internally, a byte is define as something like (sorry I don't have the real code, this is my question):
public class byte {
  int bytValue = 0;

  get {
    return bytValue;
  }

  set {
    if (value < 0 || value > 255) {
      throw;
    }
    
    bytValue = value;
  }
}

Now, let's suppose I want to create such class and call it bytePlus, which would be limited to 0 to 512. How do I create a "Value" class where when called it gives a value?
I might insist [I do not want to overload byte, I'm really using byte as an example, I intend to create a different kind of "value" type class]
Example:
public class bytePlus {
...
}

When I do something like this:
public bytePlus MyValue = 4;


I want MyValue to act like a value. Because, the "default" property would be to return a value. But I want to add also other properties (which is the easy part).
How do I define such class?
I googled to find the answer... no luck
ATTEMPT:

by the way forget the byte, let's go uint to avoid some confusion *
The suggested post custom class act as integer
propose something like:

    class BytePlus {
        private uint _value;
        
        // User-defined conversion from Digit to double 
        public static implicit operator uint(BytePlus d) {
            return d._value;
        }
    }

when I attempt:

bytePlus rrr = new bytePlus();
rrr = rrr + 1;


it doesn't work, it can't add.
"impossible to convert uint to bytePlus()"
My end goal is because there is a string property attached to the "value" that need to stay with the value from the class, when the "real" value is updated, the string value also need to be updated because it represent a kind of crc of the said value.
@shingo proposition was right but I failed to understand it because it needed some more code.
here the code based on MakePeaceGreatAgain accepted Answer
public class BytePlus {
    private uint uintValue = 0;

    public BytePlus() {
        //
    }

    public BytePlus(uint b) {
        this.Value = b;
    }

    public uint Value {
        get {
            return uintValue;
        }
        set {
            //here I can add my code...
            uintValue = value;
        }
    }

    //here I can add my other properties

    public static implicit operator uint(BytePlus d) => d.Value;
    public static implicit operator BytePlus(uint b) => new BytePlus(b);
}

then I do:
BytePlus hex32 = 4;
hex32++;


Not sure I understand what you mean. But making it a struct instead of a class will make it a value type.

Byte is a separate datatype, it corresponds to 1 ... byte of memory, it does not have internal storage with int (which is 4 bytes)

bytePlus MyValue = 4; seems like OP wants some implicit user-defined cast. See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators

@wohlstad making a struct won't allow me to add properties.

@Guru Stron: yeah you are right. Like i said, byte is just an example, I should have selected int or string for my example. I understand binary and how it shape the max value of every value type.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain: I know the example is wrong, as stated in my question (couldn't find better to explain) I'm not trying to overload the byte but to create a new defined "value" type class with it's own attribute and method.

@shingo: it seem to be that, but let me check if everything pan out. if that's the same question, what is the "right" process, should I close the question or make it like related to that other question ?

@Sigma3Wolf I got your point. The problem simply is: as soon as you convert your super-class back to a byte, all that extra-information is lost, as a byte (or whatever type you're really wrapping)  has no clue about that extra-stuff. That would only work, if your two types are informational similar - which is they represent the same data. Then your cast essentially is some kind of mapping between two types.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain: I don't intend to convert back to anything else, it's a new definition for a value class.  In the meanwhile I saw someone credited himself with "answer" that he/she/they think it's right, so I'll evaluate the answer but so far it's not suiting my needs

as long as you're really just casting your wrapped type (for instance byte)  to your wrapper (BytePlus), everything is fine. However if you also intend to do the other way, you may lose information.

struct types can have properties.

your edit turns your question into something completly new. Now you're asking: how can I overload an operator (like +) for my own type?

@MakePeaceGreatAgain I understand your point. The background value is an uint and when I send it back to user, I'm using a uint. There will be no loss of information. There is a string propertie attached to the "value" that need to stay with the value from the class, when the "real" value is updated, the string value also need to be updated because it represent a crc of the said value.

"your edit turns your question into something ...."   (again!)  Try to think about what you want to ask, and do not hide info in your question.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain: not at all. I know it's confusing because someone added and marked something as an answer and now it got removed. But I tried to make it work with the "proposed" answer and in the end, I didn't succedd to do it and the "answer" got removed. the code I put in my question show about something that "look" promising as an answer from shingo.  My initial quesiton stand, I need a "value" class. by definition a value class is something I could do: MyVar++; but in the inside of it I need to control the string value attached to that "real value"

no answer was removed at all by someone, I just removed my own because it didn't fit to your edits any more. And the proposed dupe has the exact same issue, it doesn't fit your edit. Again: you asked how to convert your type to another, which was answered by me and the dupe. Afterwards you asked: how can I change what + does, which is a completely different question. Please be as specific as possible about what you really want to achieve, not by providing what you think the solution is.

@Luuk my question is still the same. "How do I make a "value class" from wich I can use like a value but with added propertie (in that case a string).

Why don't you just add some Add-function to your class: public void Add(uint amount) { this.Value += amount; }.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain in no way I want to offend you. maybe we do not understand each other, maybe my question is ambiguous. I appreciate all your input. My question didn't changed, I simply went with the flow of suggesting proposition and I try what it mean. If I knew the answer I wouldn't ask for the question. if someone propose something, it has to be something I dont know. therefore my comprehension of it is somewhat limited. In my edit (question) I put what I tried and what didn'T work so you can understand what I'm trying. sorry for the confusion

@MakePeaceGreatAgain I could go and add Add() but then I'll have to repeat the whole alphabet of aritmetic operation. Modulus, substract, division and all. What I want is a uint class that act like an uint but with a whole new set of function and property inside. I don't know how to do that

you need to do so anyway, because the notion of + and * simply doesn't apply to all kinds of what you consider a value. For example, while string has an overload for +, what should "MyString" * "MyOtherString" return? There's no such thing as multiplying two strings. In short you need to provide these functions yourself.

Currently your question doesn't show any code for how you expect this string property to work. I'd suggest this should probably be a value type, and immutable - so that when you do myValue + 1 it creates a new value, rather than modifying an existing one. As others have already said, that means you probably want a struct, and without any setters... but it's hard to guess how to help when the requirements are vague.

@Jon Skeet: because the problem is not the string propertie but how I can intercept operation made on the value. Now I realized my question wasn't clear enough but it's hard to explain a concept based on the solution when you don't have the solution. I didn't know I needed to overload the operator, MakePeaceGreatAgain opened my eyes

"Now I realized my question wasn't clear enough but it's hard to explain a concept based on the solution when you don't have the solution" - but you can provide the code you expect to work, even if you don't know the code you'd use to implement it. If you'd provided full concrete examples of everything you want to be able to do with BytePlus from the start, it would have been much easier to help you.

Basically you can add an implict cast to your BytePlus-type, making the following possible:
BytePlus MyValue = 4;

The other way also works:
byte b = new BytePlus(4);

So you need an operator for the conversion:
class BytePlus
{
    public BytePlus(byte b)
    {
        this.Value = b;
    }
    public byte Value { ... }
    
    public static implicit operator byte(BytePlus d) => d.Value;
    public static implicit operator BytePlus(byte b) => new BytePlus(b);
}

However be aware that implicit casts imply a loseless conversion. So when converting a byte to BytePlus, you essentially add information, which is okay. However the other way is not okay, as a conversion from BytePlus to byte may lead to information-loss (a byte has no knowledge about the members in your BytePlus-class). In these scenarios it's usually better to make the operator explicit, which basically means: "there might be information-loss when doing this cast, but I'm okay with it".
See also the docs about user-defined casts: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators
When you also want some operator on your type - which means you want to provide +and - for instance, you can add so by doing this:
class BytePlus
{
    public static BytePlus operator + (BytePlus b, byte amount) => new BytePlus(b.Value + amount);
    public static BytePlus operator - (BytePlus b, byte amount) => new BytePlus(b.Value - amount);
}


you can also define an explicit operator for the first case to address the "loselessness".

that's simply not possible, as your two types have no knowledge about one another. This implies you could convert every long to int and backwards, which simply isn't possible. Making your operator explicit just makes this visible to your users.

why is it not possible? That's exactly its purpose - visibility and knowledge that it can throw. It should when there are "losses" i.e. long is bigger than the int.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain : I like that code. not sure how to adapt to my need... Can I do MyVar++; ?

@Sigma3Wolf as mentioned in my other comment to the question: only if you provide the ++-operator yourself. So overload that operator as well.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain for now, because of my lack of knowledge on that kind of thing... I'm not sure I understand why it work but your code is brillant and work. I'll accept your answer and edit the question to show what I ended up doing.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain : I'm not sure what the following line does : public static implicit operator BytePlus(uint b) => new BytePlus(b);  I'll have to test some stuff. but it work and I'll work around it to understand it better. Thanks a lot !!!
